# Filesystem damaged and can't be fixed

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck

For a while now I've had this problem. When I start, most programs don't work because they can't access files apparently.
As I reboot, the system seems to get stuck. So I run a hard restart (from the laptop button).

I end up in initramfs that tells me /dev/sda4 requires a manual fsck. So I run it, say yes to all, and then exit. At this point, the system will usually start properly. But the problem appears again at every reboot.

I also tried running fsck from the terminal after the system starts and then rebooting, but no luck. It always finds and fixes the same problems with /dev/sda4 but they're always back at the next reboot.

UPDATE 1

I checked the hard drive with Smartmontools as suggested by guiverc. The extended test was completed with read failure. Not sure how to interpret the results, I've uploaded them here: https://gofile.io/d/L9Z7u6. Does this mean my HDD is damaged?

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, but I'll suggest using commands to shutdown rather than what I assume you mean by laptop button hard restart (ie. SysRq keys direct to kernel).  If you're regularly having issues though and can't find the reason, I'd check your hardware. Is your drive healthy (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), memory good (ram test it), PSU reliable? etc.

Comment: I would run boot-repair on this one. You should boot from a usb stick with your version of Ubuntu and go through the steps described in the following link. If recommended repair doesn't help, you should try the advanced options (the advanced options worked for me).
.
https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_repair_tutorial/